# Axios put with currenly logged in user id in a node app with firebase auth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, mern

I'm currently building a chrome extension with firebase authentication and MERN stack.

I use auth context and private route in the frontend react app. I want to update a variable to specific to each user with axios put. How to specify the user id while updating with axios(put method).

I'm using custom tokens in the backend. Any idea on how to pass the uid between frontend and backend?

Answer (score 1):

You should not pass the UID itself in the request. Instead you should pass the Firebase ID Token and then verify it at the backend using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

You can get the ID Token of the current user like this and then pass it in your API request:

```
import Axios from "axios";

async makeRequest() {
  const idToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
  const response = await Axios({
    url: "YourURL",
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`},
    data: {...}
  })
  console.log(response.data)
}
```

I pass the ID Token as a Bearer token in the authorization but it's upto you.

To verify the tokens on the backend you can use the [`.verifyIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) method.

You can do the validation in an Express middleware so you don't have to copy the code again and again:

```
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const {authorization} = req.headers;
  if (!authorization) return res.sendStatus(401);
  
  const token = authorization.split(" ");
  if (token[0] !== "Bearer") return res.sendStatus(401);

  const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  console.log(decodedToken)
  req.decodedToken = decodedToken
  return next()
}


//Then on the endpoints where you need to authenticate user:
app.put("/route", authMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  //Process here
  //You can access the auth data by req.decodedToken
})
```

The `decodedToken` contains user's UID, custom claims and some metadata. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken?hl=en).