# Firebase Auth Id Token, store in DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know that the firebaes auth id token is automatically renewed by itself. When doing getIdToken().

I am now trying to use only firebase auth token id instead of JWT.

I want to ask if the flow chart I have designed is correct.

When a user signs in or signs up for the first time in the app, the firebase id token is stored in the user account table DB as access_token. And save it locally in Shared Preference.

And whenever the user enters the app, the current token id is continuously written to the server.

The user can still save the latest token in the database, and since other users do not know his token, they cannot delete or edit his post. Whenever write operation is performed, the current user getIdToken() and the access_token in the DB are checked to see if they match.

am I correct???

I don't use refresh_token separately, but I don't think it matters that much, right?

(and I don`t use currently Security Rules/Firestore)

Comment: What are you trying to do and why do you want to save the token in a database?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I just want to make A's POST unmodifiable by B. or personal informations

Comment: Why not use security rules for that? You can verify if a user is trying to modify their own post only. Can you share screenshots of your database structure and then explain what actions should a user be able to perform?

Comment: @Dharmaraj The project I am currently working on is made with mysql. So I can`t use Security Rules

Comment: In that case you should have a server in between the database and end user like Cloud Functions where you can check if a user is allowed to perform certain actions. You should not store the token anywhere but instead [verify the tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) on backend.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes, I have a node js backend webserver now, and actually verifying is really not a problem. Any app users can pass verifying.  The problem is that user A's token and user B's must be distinguished, and only user A must be able to update user A's posts.

Comment: If you check the link in my previous comment, you can verify who is the requesting user by verifying the token and checking the UID from decoded token.

Comment: @Dharmaraj But in the end, even if you can identify who is requesting it, you will also have to look up the owner token of the post and it will be in the database row.

Comment: I did not understand. You would store user's UID along with the posts not the token. The you can query a user's posts with the UID. e.g. `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author = ${user_id}`. That way a user can read their own posts only as you are verifying the token at the backend and have a valid UID.

Comment: @Dharmaraj reading is not a problem (SELECT QUERY), problem occurs when it is deletion, DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ${post_id}, in this case simple verifying is not enough..

Comment: How about `DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ${post_id} AND author = ${user_id}`? The UID is not passed from frontend directly but you are verifying the token on backend and getting the UID so this should do what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dharmaraj DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ${post_id} AND author = ${user_id} these parameters are also could be manipulated if malicious user knows query url and he also knows post_id and user_id also that is not belong to him

Comment: As mentioned already, you DO NOT pass the user ID in API request but the token. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68208639/13130697) for more information. I'd recommend checkout out [JWTs](https://jwt.io/) a bit.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yah, send a token instead of user ID. However, it is necessary to check if the token of the owner of the post matches. it requires database look up, Can you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74665988/want-to-allow-only-the-post-owner-to-delete/74666166#74666166

Comment: @Dharmaraj Hi, sorry I did a lot of research and maybe doesn\`t need to database look up.. hacker can read encoded JWT but he can`t modify so it is write-safe in worst case